# Replacing multiple elif for a dictionary for multiple functions

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I have read about C-like `switch` idiom in python be expressed as a dictionary, most examples uses a single function and a break statement. In my case I have the following `if`

```
if method == 'c3':
    Deh = buildD4(I)
    Dhe = buildD343(I-1)
elif method == 'c4':
    Deh = buildD4(I);
    Dhe = buildD4(I-1)
elif method == 'c5':
    Deh = buildD343(I)
    Dhe = buildD343(I-1)
elif method == 'e2':
    Deh = buildAE4(I)
    Dhe = buildAH4(I)
elif method == 'y2':
    Deh = buildD2(I)
    Dhe = buildD2(I-1)
    dt=dx
```

And I have rewritten as:

```
eh = {
        'c3': buildD4(I),
        'c4': buildD4(I),
        'c5': buildD343(I),
        'e2': buildAE4(I),
        'y2': buildD2(I),
}
Deh = eh[method]

he = {
        'c3': buildD343(I-1),
        'c4': buildD4(I-1),
        'c5': buildD343(I-1),
        'e2': buildAH4(I),
        'y2': buildD2(I-1),
}
Dhe = he[method]

if method == y2:
    dt=dx
```

My questions are:

1. The functions inside the dictionary are lazily evaluated, that is they are evaluated only when I assign them to `Deh` or `Dhe` ?

1.1 If don't. How can I achieve that?

2. Is there a better (more compact, readable and idiomatic) way to write it? (or the `if/elif` are the best construction?

PS: all those `build*`functions return a square matrix with the size of parameter given. `I` is an integer, `dt` and `dx` are floats and `method` is a string.

Comment: No, they are not lazily evaluated.  The values are evaluated at the time the dictionary is created.

Comment: If the argument to the build functions was consistent, you could build a dictionary from the function objects themselves, i.e. `eh = {'c3': buildD4, ...}`, and then lazily call the method afterward with `Deh = eh[method](I)`.  But the argument to the `he` functions isn't consistent -- sometimes it's `I` and sometimes it's `I-1`, so you can't do this.  (You could do it for the `eh` functions, as those all take `I` as an argument.)

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, `I`s are not consistent in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the dictionary must be constructed first, which means that all the keys and values must be evaluated. You can store functions as values, though:

   ```
   data = {'a': lambda x: print(f"hello, {x}!"), 'b': lambda x: print(f"Hi, {x}!")}
   data['a']("world")
   ```

   1.1 You can do this: `unevaluated = lambda: do_stuff()`. Now, `do_stuff` will only be called when you call `unevaluated()`, but that looks kinda ugly.
2. Using dictionaries holding individual functions may be the way to go

Comment: looks like `if/elif` are way to go.